# File is always modified in Git due to different versions of sass/compass

Tags: ruby, git, ubuntu, sass

my colleague and I are using sass and compass in our web development workflow. We got a annoying problems with the css-files after they were compiled. Git always tells us that the css file has been modified, but in fact nothing has changed only the different paths of our local instances of sass/compass differ from each other.

My colleague is using ubuntu 12.04 and installed sass/compass with gem

```
sudo gem install sass & sudo gem install compass
```

I instead use ubuntu 14.04 and installed it that way

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-compass
```

As mentioned the compiling works fine for both of use. But the compiled css-file is always modified. If I compare the both files I see that sass/compass is using another path.

This is the output of the command git log main.css

```
-/* line 17, ../../../../../var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.7/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
+/* line 17, ../../../../../usr/share/compass/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
```

What can I do in that case? I already tried to install ruby-compass on the 12.04 ubuntu, but it doesnt work with 12.04.

Is there any possibilty to fix this issue, because it is annoying that the css-file is modified everytime I do a git pull and vice versa.

thx in advance

Comment: Why not just turn off the comments in your config.rb?

Comment: @cimmanon yes you are right this also works, i added the line 

    noLineComments: true

to my grunt-config file and now it works ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a compiled file, why does it have to be checked in?

I would just remove the file from the git repo, and generate it on the server of deployment, because the paths there could again be different from either of the two of your machines, and similarly the underlying OS versions could be different, thus anyway needing a recompilation.

Just do

```
git rm main.css
echo main.css >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "msg"
```